# Installing locust on kubernetes with helm chart goes into CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, locust, helm3

I'm setting up locust@2.12.1 on kubernetes using [helm chart](https://github.com/deliveryhero/helm-charts/tree/master/stable/locust).
And in starting locust images, I get this error and containers go into CrashLoopBackOff. Is there any work around for it?

```
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust Installing collected packages: pysha3, pylru, ethereum-utils, ethereum-tester, ethereum-abi-utils, bitarray, toolz, pycryptodome, parsimonious, hexbytes, eth-typing, eth-hash, cytoolz, eth-utils, rlp, eth-keys, eth-abi, web3, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth_account
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   Running setup.py install for pysha3: started
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   Running setup.py install for pysha3: finished with status 'error'
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   × Running setup.py install for pysha3 did not run successfully.
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   │ exit code: 1
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   ╰─> [15 lines of output]
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       running install
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       /opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust         warnings.warn(
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       running build
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       running build_py
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       creating build
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       copying sha3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       running build_ext
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       building '_pysha3' extension
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/Modules
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/Modules/_sha3
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_WITH_KECCAK=1 -I/opt/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c Modules/_sha3/sha3module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/Modules/_sha3/sha3module.o
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust       [end of output]
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
locust-master-5bffc94676-6nd4q locust error: legacy-install-failure
```

[Updated] Here is the values.yaml file I used.
The error occurs in installing pip packages listed below.

```
image:
  repository: locustio/locust
  tag: 2.12.1
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

loadtest:
  locust_host: http://quorum-node-dev-tx-1.svc.cluster.local
  locust_locustfile_configmap: locustfile
  pip_packages:
  - eth_account
  - web3

master:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2000m
      memory: 1024Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 1024Mi
  logLevel: INFO

worker:
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 256Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 256Mi
  logLevel: INFO
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: `error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory`. One of the Python dependencies is trying to build a C extension module, but `gcc` isn't available. I would argue that the helm chart is Doing Something Wrong; we don't normally expect to see dependencies being installed like this at *run* time (this would normally be part of the image build process). Workarounds would be context specific; it might be easiest to open an issue in the helm chart repository to report the problem and ask for suggestions.

Comment: post the value file

Comment: @larsks Thanks. I'll open an issue if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locust installation eventually succeeded after I changed the order of pip packages of values.yaml.

- from

```
pip_packages:
  - eth_account
  - web3
```

- to

```
pip_packages:
  - eth_account
  - web3
```

I don't really know why the problem was fixed but probably it's related to library dependency issue related to
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/2396

Thanks.